# Avoiding page break in the Latex bibliography list

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, ieeetran, ieee-style

I have a problem, the references are being split by the page break in a such strange manner.

[image]

I use IEEE style and already tried `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` but it influences any other section, but not the references. I need to have reference list as compact as possible, without undesired and unnecessary page break.

I tried to google it, but did not find the answer.

### **SOLVED:** *In the IEEE template there was a line: \addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm} After conclusion and before the bibliography. When I deleted it, everything got OK. Hope it would be useful for someone.*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: check your bbl file: that looks like there is a forced page break in that entry.

Comment: Dear David,
I checked, but there is no page break in bbl file. I also find out, that if I would delete some text, references from the last page will be constricted up. And if I would add some, they will continue to move down the last page. It means that on the middle page there is always a half of the page of references, not more. If more - than they go to the next page.

Comment: It looks to me as if(for some reason) LaTeX 's output routine got screwed up and it believes that that only this amount of space is available for text. I don't think that IEEEtran is directly changing the OR or its parameters so it must be some combination of package used in your doc. Bottom line without a full example showing the behavior it is not possible to guess what the issue is. What happens if you double the entries in the bbl file? does the next page then also shows this shortening? or if you add further text after the bibliography?

Comment: This is still happening and this line does not exist in the newest template.